# Hyperledger Fabric: How would hospitals share specific patient records?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

Do we create a channel per patient or how best can hospitals share patient data? How can we use hyperledger fabric to share a specific patient info? If we have every hospital as an organisation with patients as users, what happens if we want a second hospital to get access to this patient's data to avoid duplication and have a trusted patient history?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a specific channel among all hospitals to share patient records, and I would implement rules in the chaincode to be able to give access in a controled way, not all records opened to everybody in the channel all the time. I'd also would think of implementing the data sharing using private data collections (as of HLF >= 1.2). More info on the PDC topic here: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/private-data/private-data.html.